# syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have a shell script that should accept multiple arguments.

It can either accept the argument "update" or "create". If no argument is passed, the user should get an error. However, when building my `if/elif` condition I'm getting the error:

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
```

The code:

```
firstParam=$1
echo $firstParam //update/create/{empty}

if [[ "$firstParam" == "" ]]; then
    printf "${RED}Use this script as \"tzfrs update/new [projectName]\"${NC} \n"
    exit 1
elif [[ "$firstParam" == "update"]]; then
  printf "update"
  exit 1
fi
```

If I have the script like this

```
if [[ "$firstParam" == "" ]]; then
    printf "${RED}Use this script as \"tzfrs update/new [projectName]\"${NC} \n"
    exit 1
fi
```

The error handling works, and I'm seeing the following message

`Use this script as "tzfrs update/new [projectName]"`

However, when adding the `elif` condition I'm getting the above error. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
elif [[ "$firstParam" == "update"]]; then
```

should be

```
elif [[ "$firstParam" == "update" ]]; then
```

with a space between `"update"` and `]]`

Comment: Wow, such a stupid error. Thanks for that ! :) Have to wait 11 more minutes before I can accept the answer

Comment: I can't believe I made this error! _And_ that it is so popular!

Comment: It's things like this that make me realize I wouldn't be able to do my job without the internet, and StackOverflow in particular. I've been pulling my hair out over this, and it's literally a single missing space!